# Does having a mobile site and/or iPhone App affect traffic to main website

Tags: iphone, web, mobile

We have a client who has expressed a strong interest in developing both an iPhone app and a mobile friendly version of their news website.

Their only concern is whether traffic to the current website will take a hit due to people accessing the content via the app / mobile site as this would have an impact on advertising.

We feel by not having the mobile friendly website / iPhone app you risk losing visitors to competitors that do with the ideal scenario being visitors using the app and mobile site when commuting and then visiting the main website when at their desk / home etc.

Anyway we would be very interested in any available statistics or peoples experiences on the impact mobile applications have on visitor traffic to the main website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to say without knowing more about the client, as a lot of this will depend on the nature of the site - if for example the "news" in question is particularly relevant to people on the move.

That said, I don't quite get what the issue is here, as any "lost" traffic will simply be using a different avenue to access your client's content, all of which can be tracked anyway. (The mobile site will still have traffic logs and likewise if the iPhone app loads data from a remote server.) In terms of maintaining the advertising revenue, you could for example use Apple's iAd system in the iPhone app and there's no reason why you couldn't continue to use traditional advertising on any mobile version of the web site, although I'd personally question whether there's any real need for a dedicated mobile version in the first place bearing the mind the capabilities of smart phones these days.

On the other hand, if it's a case of whether or not it's financially advisable (or indeed if there's a business case) to create a dedicated mobile site and iPhone app, etc. then that's a different issue, but I suspect that (like many) the client probably just wants an iPhone app for the supposed cachet rather than there being any real benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i know it's not an easy one to give a concrete answer but if it helps the site delivers technology news.

The clients concern is that their current revenue comes from adverts on the main website so if traffic fell so would the advertising revenue. Then the question would be whether advertising with iAd on the app and advertising on the mobile site would be enough to balance things.

Comment: The question of whether an iPhone app or mobile site is useful given the browser capabilities of smart phones is probably a debate for another day but personally I find all the pinching and zooming a tiring experience. As an exercise try reading and navigating to five articles on a mobile optimised website such as Guardian.co.uk compared to a non optimised website of your choice.